# Tarpaulin running a subset of unit test

Tags: unit-testing, rust, code-coverage, rust-cargo

I would like to know how to run a subset of tests using tarpaulin.

https://github.com/xd009642/tarpaulin - The documentation lists one argument `--tests` but that doesn't really provide a usage.

Using cargo, one can run tests such as:

```
cargo test <test_prefix> -- --nocapture
```

I would like to know how we can achieve the same using tarpaulin.

Comment: As far as I can tell the syntax is the exact same, but you have to add the test_prefix after the `--` in `cargo test` too: `cargo <test|tarpaulin> -- <test_prefix>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line

```
cargo test <test_prefix> -- --nocapture
```

is actually the same as

```
cargo test -- <test_prefix> --nocapture
```

because Cargo has a special exception that if you are passing one argument that doesn't begin with `-` (usually a test filter), you don't need to bother writing `--` too.

`tarpaulin` doesn't have that same special one-argument feature, but it does have `-- <args>` — so just use that.

```
cargo tarpaulin -- <test_prefix> --nocapture
```

Or perhaps the more conventional/universal ordering with options first

```
cargo tarpaulin -- --nocapture <test_prefix>
```

In general, all the options to `tarpaulin` go before the `--`, and all the options to the test binary (typically the built-in Rust test harness) go after it.

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up: tarpaulin seems to be cleaning and building fresh every time. I suppose `skip-clean` helps with that. How do I provide additional arguments? I tried `cargo tarpaulin -- --skip-clean --nocapture --out Html <test_name_prefix>` and it errors - `error: Unrecognized option: 'skip-clean'`

Comment: @VikasGoel That option would go before the `--` since it is part of `tarpaulin`, not the test harness: `cargo tarpaulin --skip-clean --out Html --  --nocapture <test_name_prefix>`